# $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with the cofinite topology continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be endowed with the co-finite topology.
I would like to explain why the function $f$ : $\mathbb{N}$ → $\mathbb{N}$, $n$ → $n^3$
is continuous by using the definition of continuity which states that a function $f$: X → Y is continuous if the inverse image of any open set in Y is an open set in X. In other words, I would like to be able to use the pre-image. I know that $\mathbb{N}$ with the co-finite topology is connected and therefore its image under a continuous function is connected but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: An equivalent definition of continuity is that the preimage of any closed set is closed. (This is said in the spirit of a hint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $f$ is continuos, we have to show that for all $A$ open set of $\mathbb N$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open set. An open set of $\mathbb N$ with the co-finite topology is a set such that $\mathbb N \ \backslash A$ is finite. Hence we have to show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is a set such that $\mathbb N \ \backslash \ f^{-1}(A)$ is finite.

Now:
$$\mathbb N \ \backslash \ f^{-1}(A) = \{n\in \mathbb N \ | \ n^3\notin A\} = f^{-1}(\mathbb N\ \backslash \ A)$$

By hypotesis $\mathbb N \ \backslash A$ is finite, and the map $f$ is injective; hence $\mathbb N \ \backslash \ f^{-1}(A)$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Take any open set in the image $\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ where A is finite.
Notice that: $$f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus A] = f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}]\setminus f^{-1}[A]=\mathbb{N}\setminus f^{-1}[A]$$ And therefore because your function is injective:
$$|\mathbb{N}\setminus (f^{-1}[\mathbb{N}\setminus A])|=|f^{-1}[A]|\leq |A|$$
This shows that inverse images of open sets are open, therefore f is continuous.